# make error using GNU/GCC quad precision library

Tags: c, gcc, cygwin, double, precision

When using Cygwin and GCC under Win 7 and the quad precision library:

```
gcc -c lquad.c
```

... this runs OK, but

```
gcc lquad.o
```

... produces the following error:

> /tmp/ccLM2lOn.o:lquad.c:(.text+0xdb3): undefined reference to `sqrtq'
>
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I have `#include quadmath.h` in a C source, and the `__float128` type works, but not the functions (e.g. sqrtq above).  This header file has all the relevant externs, e.g.:

```
extern __float128 sqrtq (__float128) __quadmath_throw;
```

I found a dll cygquadmath-0.dll which definitely has these functions in it.  It is in 3 places in the Cygwin installation.  Additionally, I copied it to Windows\System, but that did not help.

There is a related question here, but nothing helped me there and it is not exactly the same error: [Quadruple Precision in C++ (GCC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5451447/quadruple-precision-in-c-gcc)

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a compiler solution when what you need is a linker solution:
Your code is compiling as it should, so no change in the code would solve your problem:

> /tmp/ccLM2lOn.o:lquad.c:(.text+0xdb3): undefined reference to `sqrtq'
>
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

The `undefined reference to` errors indicate a function needed by your object is in another library.
As suggested by @Marc Glisse, try adding `-lquadmath` to your linker line.